# Showing the unit ball in $l^{\infty}$ is not compact.

Tags: metric-spaces

If $l^{\infty}$ is the set of bounded sequences of real numbers with norm $||x||_{\infty}$.

To do this I have tried to use the fact that a metric space is compact iff it is sequentially compact. So now I am trying to find a sequence with no convergent subsequence, perhaps by choosing it so that $||x_m-x_n|| > 1/2$ (so that it is not cauchy), however I am struggling to see what is actually going on and how to pick a sequence with this property.

Thanks

Comment: Let $x_n$ be $1$ in its $n$'th coordinate and $0$ in the others.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that $||x_m - x_n|| = 0$ for any m,n?

Comment: No, for $n\ne m$, $x_n-x_m$ has exactly two non-zero coordinates, the $n$'th with value $1$ and the $m$'th with value $-1$.

Comment: So in this case, we can't find a convergent subsequence because the sequence itself isn't convergent?